# how to set distfun of create_dendrogram in plotly.figure_factory

Tags: python, plotly, dendrogram

I am meeting some difficulties when drawing a dendrogram by `create_dendrogram` in `plotly.figure_factory`.

the default linkagefun (`linkagefun`) is `complete` and the default setting of distance function (`distfun`) is `scs.distance.pdist`

but the setting I want is `jaccard` for `distfun`, and `average` for `linkagefun`:
the setting I want shows below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as such

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
disMat = sch.distance.pdist(df, metric='jaccard')
disMat1 = sch.distance.squareform(disMat)
Z=sch.linkage(disMat1,method='average')
Dend=sch.dendrogram(Z,orientation='right')
plt.tick_params(
        axis='y',          
        which='both',      
        direction='in',   
        left=False,      
        right=False,         
        labelleft=False)
```

I noticed that the `linkagefun` could be set by `linkagefun=lambda x: sch.linkage(x, 'average')`, but the `distfun` can't be set by `distfun='jaccard'`, and I have no idea of how to set this function.

```py
fig = create_dendrogram(df, orientation='left',
                        labels=df.index,
                         distfun='jaccard',
                         linkagefun=lambda x: sch.linkage(x, 'average'))
fig.show()
```

the example of the df set below:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'1-7':[0,0,1,1,0,1,1],'1-2':[1,0,1,0,0,1,1],'2-3':[1,0,0,0,1,1,0],'2-2':[0,1,0,1,0,1,1],'1-1':[1,0,0,1,0,1,0],'1-3':[0,1,1,1,0,0,0],'1-5':[0,1,0,1,1,0,1]},index=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'])
```

since I need Dash to plot the figure on the web page, it seems I have to use `create_dendrogram` in plotly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `partial` from `functools` to "freeze" the parameter of `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` that specifies the distance metric.

```
    from functools import partial
    from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
    pw_jaccard_func = partial(pdist, metric='jaccard')
```

Then use the partial function as the input for `distfun`:

```
fig = create_dendrogram(df, orientation='left',
                        labels=df.index,
                        distfun=pw_jaccard_func ,
                        linkagefun=lambda x: sch.linkage(x, 'average'))
```